# Using Classic ASP to get value of a node attribute

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I have the following XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <PageMapping>
    <Applications>
       <Application name="xxx">
         <Page name='Default.aspx' IsCaptured = "true" >
            <Control name="btnSearch" IsCaptured = "true"/>
            <Control name="btnSave" IsCaptured = "true"/>
            <Control name="btnClick" IsCaptured = "true"/>
         </Page>
         <Page name='Login.aspx' IsCaptured = "true">
            <Control name="btnSearch" IsCaptured = "true"/>
         </Page>
         <Page name='Home.aspx' IsCaptured = "true" >
            <Control name="btnSearch" IsCaptured = "true"/>
         </Page>
         <Page name='User.aspx' IsCaptured = "true" />
     </Application>
   </Applications>
 </PageMapping>
```

Using ASP, how would I get the value of "name" and "IsCaptured"? I have tried all sorts of different methods, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: We need more details: is this XML local file on the server? Or is it located on different machine/website?

Comment: This XML is located on local server only

Comment: So [Rory answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573002/447356) should be correct then..

Comment: @Shadow: Not quite.  Subramani are you interested in the attributes on both Page elements and Control elements?

Comment: Yes i need for both Page and Control Elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```vbs
Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.4.0")
oXML.LoadXML(sXML) ' sXML is a variable containing the content of your XML file

For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/PageMapping/Applications/Application/Page")
    sName = oNode.GetAttribute("Name")
    sIsCaptured = oNode.GetAttribute("IsCaptured")

    ' Do something with these values here
Next

Set oXML = Nothing
```

Comment: Its not working... the XML file is available on same virtual directory. anythink needs to include? Note: I am using IE 8

Comment: @subramani just change `oXML.LoadXML(sXML)` to `oXML.Load("filename.xml")`

Comment: @Shadow: you need Server.MapPath as well.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones true, my bad! Rory can you please edit your post with this option as well?

Comment: <%@ Language=VBScript %><% Option Explicit %><HTML> <HEAD> </HEAD> <BODY> <% On Error Resume Next Dim oXML Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") oXML.async = False oXML.load (Server.MapPath("/Test1/PortalConfiguration.xml")) Dim sName Dim sIsCaptured For Each oNode In oXML.SelectNodes("/PageMapping/Applications/Application/Page") sName = oNode.GetAttribute("name") sIsCaptured = oNode.GetAttribute("IsCaptured") response.write("SName" & sName) response.write("is" & sIsCaptured) Next Set oXML = Nothing %> </BODY> </HTML>.The aboce code is not working. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change line 4 and 5 to these:

```
Dim sName : sName =  oNode.GetAttribute("Name")
Dim sIsCaptured : sIsCaptured =  oNode.GetAttribute("IsCaptured")
```