# Getting Attribute from XML node / Classic ASP

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic

given this xml

```
<provincias>
  <provincia id="2" inmuebles="4" nombre="Albacete">
    <localidad id="54" nombre="ALBACETE" inmuebles="1">
      <inmuebles>
        <inmueble id="9613" tipo="segunda-mano">
          <foto>
            url/docweb/promocion/225/00052458.JPG
          </foto>
          <tipologia>Piso</tipologia>
          <tipocalle>Plaza</tipocalle>
          <nombrecalle>ISABEL II</nombrecalle>
          <numerocalle>1</numerocalle>
          <bloque/>
          <portal/>
          <escalera/>
          <planta>5º</planta>
          <puerta>A</puerta>
          <codigopostal>02005</codigopostal>
          <superficie>97</superficie>
          <superficieutil>86</superficieutil>
          <habitaciones>4</habitaciones>
          <aseos>2</aseos>
          <geolocalizacion>38.999526,-1.861082</geolocalizacion>
          <imagen src="url.../docweb/promocion/225/00052458.JPG"/>
        </inmueble>
      </inmuebles>
    </localidad>
  </provincia>
</provincias>
```

How can I access the  tag "nombre" attribute? I've tried the following with no success:

```vb
set XmlDoc = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XmlDoc.async = false    
set provincias = XmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("provincia")

For Each provincia in provincias
  d1_provincia_nombre = provincia.getAttribute("nombre").value
```

But i keep getting : a `Required object : '[string: "Albacete"]'` error.

Comment: Alrite after trying some other stuff the problem was changing the line to this : d1_provincia_nombre = provincia.GetAttribute("nombre")

Comment: Sorry just seen your comment, had post window open for quite a while. If you want to post and accept your answer please do. I'll leave mine here for anyone else who comes along. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yours was just as good and a lot more clear than than my comment,thanks again! :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit,I really need tp learn to format properly here..

Comment: No problem more help can be found - [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is you're specifying `.value` on your `getAttribute` when the `XML DOM` doesn't support it.

Try this;

```vb
'Specifying .value will give an undefined or object required error
d1_provincia_nombre = provincia.getAttribute("nombre")
```

See - [Using Classic ASP to get value of a node attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8573002/692942) for more information on traversing the [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) DOM in [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic).

**Edit:** Sorry just seen your comment, had post window open for quite a while. If you want to post and accept your answer please do. I'll leave mine here for anyone else who comes along.